# ShadowRoot coming back as Null - ShadowRoot shows as open

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to select the Shadow root in Javascript so I can style the inner element. But when using the elem.shadowRoot it returns Null although the ShadowRoot is the next element. Below I have pasted my debugging and a picture of the results

This is the first time I am using shadowRoot so I could be missing something obvious.

```
console.log("target");
console.log(target);

console.log("target.firstChild");
console.log(target.firstChild);

console.log("target.shadowroot");
console.log(target.shadowRoot);

console.log("target.firstChild.shadowroot");
console.log(target.firstChild.shadowRoot);

console.log("ha-card");
console.log(target.querySelector("ha-card"));
```

[image: Results of Debugging]

Comment: The initial answer wasn't correct, my apologies. I've edited it, it would be nice if you included your html, too. So that it could be properly looked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code example is targeting, `target.shadowroot` instead of the shadowroot element itself.

Also check out the docs for using the firstChild method.  It maybe targeting incorrectly.